# Ошибка при публикации проекта Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, сборка, assembly, публикация-приложений

Не могу опубликовать абсолютно любой проект (даже пустой) в Visual Studio 2019 Community.
В журнале вывода такая информация:

```
2>------ Начало публикации: проект: Empty1, Конфигурация: Release Any CPU ------
2>Определение проектов для восстановления...
2>Не удалось загрузить индекс службы для источника https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
2>  Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса.
2>  Запрос был прерван: Не удалось создать защищенный канал SSL/TLS.
========== Сборка: успешно: 1, с ошибками: 0, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
========== Публикация: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

В файле "tmp4D94.tmp" такая информация:

```
22.09.2021 17:05:44
System.AggregateException: Произошла одна или несколько ошибок. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: При публикации произошла ошибка. Не удалось определить причину ошибки. Дополнительные сведения см. в журнале вывода.
--- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
```

В чем проблема, **уважаемые** пользователи?

Comment: Дата и время на компьютере правильно настроены?

Comment: @aepot да, настроены правильно. VPN не использую.

Comment: Версия Windows какая? TLS 1.2 поддерживается в системе? Антивирусы стоят?

Comment: Оно? https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/8176

Comment: @aepot Windows 7 Максимальная, пиратка. Антивирусов нет. Я посмотрел в inetcpl. cpl, и там TLS 1.2 присутствует, однако галочка "Использовать TLS 1.2" отключена. Включу, может поможет.

Comment: Накатите уже десятку. Семера технически устарела. Про то как прикрутить TLS1.2 к семерке есть в посте на гитхабе по ссылке выше.

Comment: @aepot Я согласен с Вами. Спасибо за помощь :)